# Woothemes Flexslider 2 missing direction nav buttons

Tags: jquery, flexslider, nav, woothemes

I've been trying to find an answer regarding 'invisible nav features' for flexslider v2.0 but I've found nothing that answers my exact question online.  Maybe it's because adding the basic slider to your page should be a no-brainer. =/

In any case, I'm hoping somebody could shed light on the reason for why my slider is not showing the 'next' and 'prev' controls.

I've followed the three steps provided by woothemes and have also added the `bg_direction_nav.png` file to my 'images' folder.

What's odd is that when I hover over the area where the controls should be, I can click and switch between my images so I know it exists, it's just not visible.

Here's the css:

```css
.flex-direction-nav {*height: 0;}
.flex-direction-nav a {width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -20px 0 0; display: block; background: url(images/bg_direction_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {background-position: 100% 0; right: -36px; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {left: -36px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next {opacity: 1 !important; right: 5px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev {opacity: 1 !important; left: 5px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next:hover, .flexslider:hover .flex-prev:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {opacity: .3!important; filter:alpha(opacity=30); cursor: default;}
```

Please let me know if I should be providing anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue. Discovered they have replaced graphic .png with a font file. Soooo, copy the font directory included in the download onto your server. Remap path in CSS. I had to add '/'  to src:url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot'); before 'fonts...' So this: src:url('/fonts/flexslider-icon.eot'); Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the JS try `directionNav: true`

```
$('#mainslider').flexslider({  
 directionNav: true
});
```